# How to fix the error "[6750] Error loading Python lib" and "dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found"

Tags: python, error-handling, dlib-python

This question is more about an error message.
I've been trying to install a software called [protostar](https://docs.swmansion.com/protostar/docs/tutorials/installation) using

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/software-mansion/protostar/master/install.sh | bash
```

Installation went well, but then when running protostar i get the following error

```
protostar -v
[6750] Error loading Python lib
'/home/myname/.protostar/dist/protostar/libpython3.9.so.1.0': 
dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found 
(required by /home/myname/.protostar/dist/protostar/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
```

What would be the best way to go about fixing this?

Comment: Recompile the software against the libc you actually have instead of using someone else's precompiled binaries.

Comment: If you're just installing someone else's software and _not_ willing to recompile it yourself, I don't see how this is on-topic here at all, as Stack Overflow's scope is exclusively limited to questions about _software development_.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for clarifying. Feel free to close this question. I am trying to develop using protostar and tgis error got in the way, so thats why I thought stack overflow might be a good address for this.